# invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::vector<double>&’ from an rvalue of type

Tags: c++

I am learning c++ and trying some things. The compiler is not throwing an error at comment 2 line.

```
int main(){
   vector<double> a1;
   a1.push_back(3);
   a1.push_back(7);
   a1.push_back(2);
   vector<double>& a2 = a1;          //COMMENT 1: This line has no error
   vector<double>& a4 = print(a2);   //COMMENT 2: Why this line has error? R value is an object then it should be referenced by a4? 
   return 0;
}

vector<double> print(vector<double>& a3){
   cout<<"In print function the size of vector is :";
   cout<<a3.size()<<endl;
   return a3;
}
```

Comment: You can't bind a non const reference to a temporary.

Comment: How a3 is a tempraory? It was declared? I know my concept is loose. Please clarify.

Comment: @Bhaskar It's a temporary simply because it's the return value of a function. (Apart from the exact terminology, it's really trivial, conceptually.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Blehh, so... yes, the return value is a temporary. And as such, it doesn't make sense to hold a reference to it (just imagine: a reference that refers to nothing when the temporary is destroyed). Thus, it's disallowed.

You can fix this in several ways:

I. Hold a const reference to it, as in

```
const vector<double> &retVal = print();
```

const references extend the lifetime of the bound temporary to the lifetime of the reference.

II. Simply return it by value:

```
vector<double> retVal = print();
```

III. Return a reference to an object that you **know** will have sufficient lifetime, e. g. a class member:

```
class Foo {
    vector<double> vec;
    public:
    vector<double> &print() {
        return vec;
    }
};

Foo f;
vector<double> &retVal = f.print();
```

***DO NOT,*** however, return a reference to a temporary from the function like this:

```
// this is wrong:
vector<double> &print()
{
    vector<double> v;
    return v;
}
```

because it invokes **undefined behavior.** (Note that this is different from your example, because you return the argument of the function which is of course alive, but it's worth noting this case as it's a common mistake to make.)

Answer (score 3):

Your return type of `print` is not a reference, so, you return a copy of `a3`. It's temporary and you can't bind it to a reference.

You could fix this with:

```
vector<double>& print(vector<double>& a3){
//            ^
// note the ampersand here
```

Comment: And here you are a nice piece of undefined behavior.

Comment: @H2CO3, Hmm. Why? `a3` is a reference too.

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't notice that it was the function argument itself.